# python - How can I retrain an ONNX model?

Tags: python, dataset, training-data, onnx

I have implemented a python code that uses an scikit learn machine learning algorithm (SVR) and after the training i export it in an onnx file. The initial dataset contains data from 2023.

After on month there will be more data that should update my model (dataset of January).

Can I update the existing onnx model with my new data?
How to deal with new data and my existing exported model?

Thank you

The only way i have considered is to merge the first dataset with the new data and then retrain.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.